# Why do I have to link these libraries twice for LLVM?

Tags: c++, linker, llvm

I'm trying to compile a sample LLVM program. The linker step uses this command.

```
llvm-config-3.2 --ldflags --libs
```

That results in the following command.

```
g++  -o bin/Debug/test-llvm obj/Debug/main.o   -L/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib  -lpthread -lffi -ldl -lm  (a boat load of LLVM libraries here)
```

However, it fails to link. I get errors like this.

```
undefined reference to ffi_type_float
```

So, I added `-lffi` and `-ldl` to the end.

```
g++  -o bin/Debug/test-llvm obj/Debug/main.o   -L/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib  -lpthread -lffi -ldl -lm  (a boat load of LLVM libraries here) -lffi -ldl
```

So, yes, they show up TWICE in the command... but it works this way. Why? They are clearly referenced earlier in the arguments.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/45141/489590 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linker order - GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc)

Comment: Not a duplicate; although one of the answers on the other question happens to address this question, they're still different questions.

Comment: Perhaps I could reframe the question: Why does `llvm-config` link stuff in the wrong order regardless of the argument order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I have to link these libraries twice

Because the order of archive libraries on command line [matters](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.htmlhttps://web.archive.org/web/20180627210132/http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html), and yours is wrong.

Comment: I tried swapping the `--ldflags` and the `--libs` to no avail. Is there another way I can adjust them? So far, I don't know what else to do other than put them in twice. =/

Comment: Once you read and understand the linked document, you *should* know what else you can do.

Answer (score 5):

One or more of the libraries appearing on the command line after `-lffi` and `-ldl` refer to symbol(s) defined in one of those libraries. But the linker has already finished scanning `libffi` and `libdl` and does not rescan them for these symbols. This circular dependency can be resolved by forcing the linker to scan those libraries again by re-listing their names at the end of the list.

A more scalable solution is to use `--start-group archives --end-group` option to list the libraries to link to. Quoting from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld):

> -( *archives* -)
>   `--start-group` *archives* `--end-group`
>       The archives should be a list of archive files. They may be either explicit file names, or -l options.
>
> The specified archives are searched repeatedly until no new undefined references are created. Normally, an archive is searched
>   only once in the order that it is specified on the command line. If a
>   symbol in that archive is needed to resolve an undefined symbol
>   referred to by an object in an archive that appears later on the
>   command line, the linker would not be able to resolve that reference.
>   By grouping the archives, they all be searched repeatedly until all
>   possible references are resolved.
>
> Using this option has a significant performance cost. It is best to use it only when there are unavoidable circular references between
>   two or more archives.

So your command line would look like this:

```
g++ -o bin/Debug/test-llvm obj/Debug/main.o -L/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib --start-group -lpthread -lffi -ldl -lm ... --end-group
```

Comment: The --start/--end-group is a crutch, not a real solution. Here it will "fix" the problem, but is the wrong soltion. The right solution is to order libraries correctly.

Comment: @EmployedRussian It's definitely not an ideal solution, but given several libraries with circular dependencies to link to, ordering them manually turns into enough of a maintenance nightmare that the *crutch* starts to look very attractive.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I found the solution. Swapping the flags didn't actually change the order. I had to break it out into two separate calls.

```
llvm-config-3.2 --libs
llvm-config-3.2 --ldflags
```

And yeah, this is technically answered in that other question: [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc)

I still just think this question is relevant because doing what the docs told me to do led me into danger. :(